# Как лучше хранить данные в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Если делать что-то вроде анкеты, по которой потом будет фильтр (поиск), как лучше хранить информацию?

```
age  town  rost  ves  cvet_volos  razmer_obuvi  etc.
 22   1     154   45      2             36      ...
```

Или записать где-то порядок столбцов и хранить всё строкой

```
id  data
1   22-1-154-45-2-36
```

Столбцы будут со временем увеличиваться, то есть, пунктов в анкете будет становиться всё больше и больше. Есть какое-нибудь ограничение на столбцы? А на запрос?

Если использовать первый вариант, запрос будет вида:

```
ла ла ла WHERE ... AND... AND... AND... AND...
```

Какое тут ограничение? Да и даже если ограничения нет, это же будут очень тяжёлые запросы? Или MySQL быстрая и ей не тяжело будет обрабатывать запрос со 100 условиями?

И вообще, как лучше всего сделать? Какие ещё способы есть? Правильные, так сказать :)

Comment: Ну, во-первых, прекратите мешать французский с нижегородским...

Comment: @karmadro4, о великий и могучий, я готова познать истину с уст твоих. :)

Comment: Храните так, как вам удобно, а для поиска используйте что-то типа [apache lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/).

Comment: А зачем там `AND...AND...AND`? Вы собираетесь выбирать ряды по совокупности всех столбцов? Странное занятие. Если нужен один ряд — для этого есть суррогатный ключ `id`. А если не один — как Вы представляете себе аналог `WHERE town = 1 AND cvet_volos = 2` для формата `'22-1-154-45-2-36'`? `LIKE '%-1-%-%-2-%'` очень неудачная идея. А `WHERE town = 1 AND ves > 120` — вообще дохлый номер.

Индексы в помощь.

Comment: @drdaeman, я себе представляла что запрос всегда будет содержать все данные. То есть, все пункты анкеты обязательны для заполнения, тогда LIKE не нужен, просто ищем ряды, где в 'data' хранится '22-1-154-45-2-36'.

Но мне уже не нравится эта затея. :)

Comment: @Angelina_Jo, MySQL может в кириллицу в именах объектов, так что если лень брать словарь, можете сделать в стиле Access, гюсско-гюсско.

Comment: А вместо age лучше birthday. Через некоторое время мороки будет меньше.

Comment: @avp, спасибки. :) Это просто образец. :)

Comment: Если есть выбор — тут больше документ-ориентированные базы смотрятся типа CouchDB (ну или MongoDB, если данные на выброс), нежели реляционные.

Comment: @drdaeman Яростно плюсую. Каждой задаче - свой инструмент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть способ с key -> value, но он не очень удобен для поиска.

Первый Ваш вариант самый удобный для поиска. Запросы  вполне обычные. Да и индексацию по приоритетным столбцам всегда можно сделать.

Второй более гибкий в плане добавления столбцов, но целенаправленный поиск по какой-либо колонке будет сложным.

Comment: Гибко?! Просто оцените объем работ для добавления атрибута `dlina_uschej` перед атрибутом `razmer_obuvi`.

Comment: @karmadro4, мне нужно всегда только - после. :)

Comment: Для второго варианта лучше уж засериализировать данные и записывать в текстовое поле. Но с поиском будут проблемы, при любом формате записи данных.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще вариант хранить в виде таблицы значений свойств. Т.е. для каждой анкеты создается n записей в таблице значений свойств с полями `anketa_id, property_id, property_value`.

Такой метод хранения далек от оптимального в плане скорости доступа к данным (по сравнению с обычной таблицей) и удобства внесения изменений, а также разнородных данных (в частности разных типов), однако позволяет менять (добавлять) состав этих свойств на лету без изменения структуры базы.

Такой метод хранения используется, например, в битриксе для свойств товаров. В 1С тоже любят всякие разные свойства, притом с составным типом.

Чтобы работать как плоской таблицей из первого пункта циклом по таблице свойств строится простой запрос:

```
select anketa.id, 
  pv1.property_value age,
  pv2.property_value town
...
from anketa
  left join prop_values pv1 on anketa.id=pv1.anketa_id and pv1.property_id=1
  left join prop_values pv2 on anketa.id=pv2.anketa_id and pv2.property_id=2
...
```

для этого запроса можно создать соответствующий view и менять его при добавлении новых свойств. индексов в зависимости от потребностей тут может понадобиться несколько разных (в том числе составных).

Вариант не лишенный недостатков, но для определенных задач типа вашей, имхо, приемлем.